# How to import product data to a specific website

Tags: magento2, magento-2.3

I want to import **different product price for specific website**.

When product price is imported to specific store view, structure is like this:

```
sku,store_view_code,name
1111,,"Default name"
1111,et,"Translated name"
1111,ru,"Another translation"
```

But how it should look like, if possible, for specific website?

Comment: You can achieve this by rest API check this out. 
https://roshanyadav007.wordpress.com/2021/03/21/how-to-update-product-using-rest-api-magento-2/

Comment: rest/<store_code>/V1/products/